# Android clickable span click activate all TextView not only spannable text

Tags: android, spannable

Good afternoon. Could you help me with a clickable span? The fact is that when I assign a clickable substring at the end of an origin String, not only the text becomes clickable, but also the entire TextView area to the right of the substring, which is bad for me (it is necessary that only a substring is clickable. Can you advise me something ? match parent for my textview is required. Unfortunately, programmatically adding " " to the original string is also unacceptable to me. Pastebin link with code: [here](https://pastebin.com/BS2xRrm1). I created a video on my Dropbox:

bad work my programm:
[dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cw83as4pbddu5v5/click%20mouse%20no%20spannable%20toast%20bad%20for%20me.wmv?dl=0)

I want it to work like this
[dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sewb821c97umbz5/click%20mouse%20no%20spannable%20toast%20not%20show%20good%20for%20me.wmv?dl=0)

My TextView needs the following layout

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    SpannableString spanable = new SpannableString("my clickable span");

    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "click span", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    spanable.setSpan(clickableSpan, 13, 17, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

    textView.setText(spanable);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set all text using length.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view);

    String strService = "my clickable span";

    int serviceStart = strService.indexOf("my clickable span");
    int serviceEnd = serviceStart + "my clickable span".length();

    SpannableString spanable = new SpannableString(strService);

    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "click span", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    spanable.setSpan(clickableSpan, serviceStart, serviceEnd, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

    textView.setText(spanable);
    textView.setClickable(true);  //add clickable
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this also does not work, I click in the lower right corner of the screen, and the clickable span works, but it should not work.

Comment: can you show what you make ui? or what you expect ui?

Comment: i update my question, where i add link video my problem and what i want.

Comment: ok. I think you have to change width, and height for what you want. If you can't this. make a View (this view have transparent background). and set click event.

Comment: Could you please explain what "make View" means?

Comment: make View means not set click event in textView, set click event in empty view in front of textview. cause now your textview is `match_parent`